# postgresql order by

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

My table has a 'number' column which ranges from 0 to around 1000.  I want to select everything from the table while ordering it by number.  However, I want the rows with number=0 to appear last.  I could do it in two queries:

```
select * from channel_table where number > 0 order by number;
select * from channel_table where number = 0;
```

But I'm guessing there is a one-line solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you only have one exceptional case, you can use nullif with the nulls clause. Otherwise you would need to order by various case statements to get more complicated ordering logic.

```
select * from channel_table 
order by nullif(number, 0) nulls last
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this to simple?

```
select * from channel_table order by number desc;
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I want it ordered 1..1000 and then the zeros.